# iteration not following list values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, iteration

I want to convert sentence in `sentences` to vector. I have 33 sentences but only get 27 vector.

Here is the .csv [data_cleaned.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10s0gxqilsygyz-mRU5EEkWbW5mBYSKQU/view?usp=sharing)

In this code, the variable sentences have 33 values, but iteration only work until 27.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_cleaned.csv', sep=',').dropna()
df.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 0':'id'}, inplace = True)

sentences = df.iloc[0:, 1]

sentences_vector = {}
for sentence in sentences:
    sum_value = randint(1,10) #vector example
    sentence_id = df.index[df.iloc[0:, 1]==sentence]
    sentences_vector[sentence_id[0]] = sum_value
    
print(sentences_vector)
```

the sentence_id value shows `Int64Index([27, 33], dtype='int64')`.
is there any relation between sentence_id and iteration?

Comment: Please share a [mre]

Comment: randip - gives an error message

Answer (score 0):

> is there any relation between sentence_id and iteration?

Yes, it will change by the `sentence`

```py
# You are selecting column 1 value
sentences = df.iloc[0:, 1]

# Loop the column 1 value
for sentence in sentences:
    # The index of value in column 1 that is equal with `sentence`
    sentence_id = df.index[df.iloc[0:, 1]==sentence]

    # Add the first duplicated index of `sentence` to `sentences_vector`
    sentences_vector[sentence_id[0]] = sum_value
```

If there are duplicated items in column 1, since you always add the first duplicated index value to `sentences_vector`. Therefore, the length of `sentences_vector` is not equal with `sentences`.

Let's say your column 1 value is

```
1
1
```

`df.index` will both return `[0,1]` in iteration, when adding second `0` to `sentences_vector`, since it is a dictionary, it only updates the value.

Comment: in this case should be 34 times iteration (there are 34 rows in `sentences` variable), but there is only 28 iteration. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: but my column 1 values are all unique.

Comment: @FahrulAzimi It didn't. You can check with `print(df.iloc[:, 1].duplicated())`.